# Unble to get arabic description when calling document service of dynamic Ax in mule esb

Tags: mule, dynamics-ax-2012

we are using Document service of dynamic Ax  and trying to get data in mule esb using dynamic ax connector.
Rest all data is coming correct, but only we are unable to get arabic desc.
Please find the below screen shot

Any help

[image]

Comment: Your XML file declares UTF-8 encoding, which includes Arabic characters. Are you sure the file was properly written using UTF-8 and read as UTF-8? Maybe your file was written using another encoding but the UTF-8 declaration remained, or you are trying to read it using a non-UTF-8 encoding.